# Infinite circular well and Bessel functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, eigenvalue

When we study one particle in the infinite circular well we have a potential $$
V(r) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & r\le a\\
\infty & r>a
\end{cases}
$$

so that TISE is:

$$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(r)\right)\psi(r,\theta)=E\psi(r,\theta)$$

after writing the Laplacian in polar coordinates and looking for an eigenfunction of the type $\psi(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ we obtain for $\Theta(\theta)$ the eigenfunction of a particle in a ring and for the radial part we obtain that the solutions are Bessel functions with certain boundary conditions.

**The question is:**
since we use the separation of variables method, if I look only at the radial part with a certain angle $\theta$, I'm moving along the radius, so why don't we just say that the eigenfunctions are the same of infinite unidimensional potential well with same eigenvalues, namely:

$\psi(x)=B\sin(\frac{n\pi r}{a})$

and the total eigenfunctions:

$\psi(r,\theta)=B\sin(\frac{n\pi r}{a})\Theta(\theta)$

In the case of a finite length cylinder with a particle moving only on the lateral surface, we have something like this, the total eigenfunction is the product of $\Phi(\phi)$ and the eigenfunction of a infinite unidimensional well along the $z$ axis, namely: $\psi(z,\phi)=Be^{im\phi}\sin(\frac{n\pi z}{L})$

Comment: The radial equation contains effective potential, $V_{\rm eff}(r)=V(r)+\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2mr^2}$ instead of $V(r)$.

Comment: Also, the Laplacian is not equal to $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}$ in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: to add to @SRS : for $\ell=0$ you get a $\sin$ divided by $r$, but for $\ell\ne 0$ you need to explicitly account for the centrifugal term and the sines become Bessels…

Comment: @SRS In the Laplacian in polar coordinates don't we have $L_z^2$? So in the effective potential we have $V(r)+\frac{\hbar^2 l_z^2}{2mr^2}$?